# ASP MVC jquery function not working in partial view but working in main view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, partial-views

I have a main view with search criteria. Main view contains a partial view with an `html` table. The search results are loaded via `ajax`.

Now i am trying to implement `edit`, `create` and `delete` via `bootstrap modal`. So in the `partial view` on table row button click event i added a function to open the modal like this

```
<button class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Location Details" type="button" onclick="ShowModal();">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-info"></i>
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowModal() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        //return false;
    }
</script>
```

This function does not work if placed in the `partial view`. However, once i place the same function inside my `main view`, the modal opens properly.

**Why does this happen?**

The reason why i wanted to have the `script` inside my `partial view`, is because i wanted to keep my client side code together so it is easier to understand and maintain.

**Edit**

The following is my `main view` together with related `scripts`:

```
@model MVC_Replica.Models.LocationSearchViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "Locations", FormMethod.Get)){
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="">
                <h1 class="page-header" id="lblDboard">Location List</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LocationSearch.LocationName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Location Name", @name = "locationName" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
                <input type="button" id="cmdSearch" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" id="locationGrid">
        @Html.Partial("_LocationGrid")
    </div>
</div>
}
```

An the `scripts`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
        $('#cmdSearch').click(function () {
            var locationName = $('#LocationSearch_LocationName').val();

            $('#locationGrid').block({ message: '<img src="../media/ajax-loading.gif"/>' });

            setTimeout(SearchLocations, 2000);

            function SearchLocations() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Locations/SearchLocations",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { 'locationName': locationName },
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#locationGrid').empty();
                        $('#locationGrid').html(response);

                        $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
                    },
                    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, errorText, thrownError) {
                        alert(xmlHttpRequest + '|' + errorText + '|' + thrownError);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>    <!--Search Locations AJAX-->
```

**Partial View HTML**

```
@model MVC_Replica.Models.LocationSearchViewModel
@{
    IEnumerable<MVC_Replica.Models.Location> location = Model.LocationList;
    Layout = null;
}
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <button class="btn btn-outline btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Create New Location" data-placement="bottom"
                        onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Locations")';return false;">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i>&nbsp; Create
                </button>
            </th>
            <th>
                Location Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Date Created
            </th>
            <th>
                Location State
            </th>

        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in location)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit Location"
                            onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Locations", new  { id=item.LocationId})';return false;">
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Location Details" type="button"
                            onclick="ShowModal();">
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-info"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete Location"
                            onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Locations", new  { id=item.LocationId})';return false;">
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-remove"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateCreated)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LocationState)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>

</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any exception in your browser error log ?

Comment: Scripts should not be in partials. Apart from them being inline, if you have multiple partials in the view (which you appear to have), it can cause problems.

Comment: I have been handling such scenarios and ended up understanding why this happens, I can help you understand it better. But before that I want to know how you are loading your partial view

Comment: I have checked the console and indeed i am getting an error: ReferenceError: ShowModal is not defined. I am going to edit my questions to show full scenario

Comment: I think everything is in place. Try placing your script in partial view and inside a document ready event. I think it must execute.

Comment: i will give it a try just now, but from what i am reading now, it is not a best practice to keep scripts in partial views. Correct? @Reddy

Comment: Some say so beacuse they find issues when placing scripts in partial view :), But I am against it, What if we have a 1 page application where all the pages are loaded via AJAX. all must be a partial view, and we can afford to load entire application module scripts at once.

Comment: Dont worry Cosmos, give it a try and let me know. I have built a plugin in handle exactly this jquery complexity in partial views. I will share it with you. But I don't think we would have to do that since your code looks right

Comment: @Reddy ,true, makes sense! I have tried placing ShowModal inside document ready event, and i get the same error:ReferenceError: ShowModal is not defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103697/discussion-between-reddy-and-cosmos-banda).

Comment: OMG I dont belive I missed it. Remove the onclick event of the button and set the event in jquery script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of yours in the partial page....

```
 <button class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Location Details" type="button"
                        onclick="ShowModal();">
```

So when you do a  `$('#locationGrid').html(response);`in your ajax call the page is added into the DOM and triggers a document ready event if any in your partial page scripts,So when the HTML is added to the DOM it starts to parse from top, while the HTML is being parsed the above line is hit and it tries to find a function with name ShowModal but it isn't loaded yet into the DOM. So you can either **place your script in the beginning of your partial page** so that the script tag is parsed prior to coming to this line and function is available. **OR** you can **remove the onclick** from the button tag and **register the button click event in document ready function**. That way you don't have to worry about the position where the script is placed.

Let me know if this resolved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using partial views I assume that you use them in an iterative manner. That means that you are going to create the same java script function more than once.

This is the reason why it doesn't work.

You should avoid using scripts in partial views.